# Filter values from array

Tags: javascript

I try to filter values from the next:

```js
const data = [
    {
        car: 'audi',
        age: 2,
        power: 200
    },
    {
        car: 'bmw',
        age: 32,
        power: 100
    },
    {
        car: 'mercedes',
        age: 21,
        power: 150
    },
];

const getRes = (data, keyTxt) => {

    return data.map(i => {
        return {
            [keyTxt]: (
                Object.entries(i).filter(j => !'car'.includes(j))
            )
        }
    })
};
console.log(getRes(data, 'age'));
```

I try to check if word `car` exists in `Object.entries()`, and if it exists to delete all arrays which include the word and to get something like this:

```js
  {
    "age": [
     
      [
        "age",
        2
      ],
      [
        "power",
        200
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "age": [
     
      [
        "age",
        32
      ],
      [
        "power",
        100
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "age": [
     
      [
        "age",
        21
      ],
      [
        "power",
        150
      ]
    ]
  }
```

What is wrong with my code and why the filter does no work? How to make this code to be able to get what i described above?

Comment: j.includes('car').  although it should really be j[0]!=='car'

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight correction in `.includes`

```js
const data = [
    {
        car: 'audi',
        age: 2,
        power: 200
    },
    {
        car: 'bmw',
        age: 32,
        power: 100
    },
    {
        car: 'mercedes',
        age: 21,
        power: 150
    },
];

const getRes = (data, keyTxt) => {

    return data.map(i => {
        return {
            [keyTxt]: (
                Object.entries(i).filter(j => !j.includes('car'))
            )
        }
    })
};
console.log(getRes(data, 'age'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
  Object.entries(i).filter(j => !j.includes('car'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either destructure the entries or reference them by index.

```
const getRes = (data, keyTxt) => {
  return data.map((entry) => {
    return {
      [keyTxt]: Object.entries(entry).filter(([key]) => key != 'car')
    };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.map()` and use `delete` to delete the property you dont need. Then return an Object with with your dynamic key name and `Object.entries()` as its value

```js
const data = [
    {
        car: 'audi',
        age: 2,
        power: 200
    },
    {
        car: 'bmw',
        age: 32,
        power: 100
    },
    {
        car: 'mercedes',
        age: 21,
        power: 150
    },
];


let result = (data, txt) => {
   return data.map(el => {
      delete el.car;
      return {
         [txt]: Object.entries(el)
      };
   })
}


console.log(result(data, "age"));
```